# 403 Missing or insufficient permissions while using Firestore in a Container

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, containers

I have built a container which uses the Cloud Storage and Firestore. I am able to access the storage but not firestore. The service account I am using is a Owner.

**DockerFile:**

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY packages-file.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY cred.json cred.json
ENV  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS "/usr/src/app/cred.json"

COPY . .
CMD ["main.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3","main.py"]
```

**main.py**

```
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client(project=projectID)
```

**Error**

[image: Error image]

Comment: Is the Storage bucket public? I mean, are you sure you are correctly using the service account from inside the container? Have you been able to use that service account with Firestore outside the container?

Comment: My bad..I used the same service account outside the container. It gave the same issue. But I have given Owner has the role. Y am I still geting access issues then

Comment: The storage bucket is not public

Comment: I created a new service account with Owner as the role..and its working..Finally

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Comment: don't post a screenshot of error

Comment: @Jasmine, if there is a solution for this issue that you would like to share with the community, please do not hesitate to create an answer for this question.